# Ember errors not populated in model with RESTAdapter in Ember 2.4.5 and Ember DATA 2.4.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm trying to handle server errors in an Ember application.

I'm running the following code in ember app:

```
customization.save().catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      console.log(customization.get('errors'));
      console.log(customization.get('errors.length'));
    });
```

And my server is answering 422 status with the following json in payload:

```
{  
   "errors":[  
      {  
         "code":"app.customization.validationError.duplicateCustomizationName",
         "detail":"a customization with same name already exists",
         "source":{  
            "pointer":"customization/name"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The error is an `InvalidError`, but `customization.get('errors.length')` is always 0.

I'm using a DS.RESTAdapter along with DS.RESTSerializer in Ember 2.4.5 with Ember DATA 2.4.0.

What am I missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured it out. The path in `source.pointer` MUST be in JSONAPI style even if you're not using DS.JSONAPIAdapter.

Sending this:

```
...
"pointer":"data/attributes/name"
...
```

Solves this issue.

I thought the path in pointer referred to the path of the field in the actual JSON corresponding to the model, but that's apparently wrong.